# Count unique values IF certain text is found

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I want to count the unique values against each name. The image below will explain what I need. Here you can see that **Second** appears 5 times in the name column but it contains only 2 unique values. I have tried the frequency method but it counts all the unique values without considering the name. Any help or suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see your row numbers from that screenshot, so I'll presume that the headers for your source table are in row 3.

In `F5`, **array formula****:

`=COUNT(1/FREQUENCY(IF(B$4:B$16=E5,C$4:C$16),C$4:C$16))`

and copied down.

To incorporate Defined Names for your two source ranges, go to *Name Manager* (*Formulas* tab) and create three new Defined Names:

*Name*: `LRow`
*Refers to*: `=MATCH(REPT("z",255),$B:$B)`

*Name*: `Names`
*Refers to*: `=$B$4:INDEX($B:$B,LRow)`

*Name*: `Values`
*Refers to*: `=$C$4:INDEX($C:$C,LRow)`

The array formula then becomes:

`=COUNT(1/FREQUENCY(IF(Names=E5,Values),Values))`

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: I have updated the screenshot. What if we only know the column and don't know the rows in which the names exist. Like cant we select the whole column instead? (B:B)

Comment: Unless you actually have data extending all the way down to row 1048576, then referencing an entire column would be a terrible idea. There are two general approaches here: 1) Choose a suitably low, though sufficient, upper bound for the end row being referenced; 2) Make your ranges dynamic, such that they automatically adjust as your data expands/contracts. I can show you how to do the latter if you wish.

Comment: Added. I have no idea what you mean by your latest comment - sorry.

Comment: `B$4:B$16=E5`
How can I use it like this `B$4:B$16="First"`

Comment: Precisely as you give, including the quotation marks around First.

Comment: Thank you for your time.